# getDisplayValues() not writing as strings

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm trying to write a script that pulls the values from a column in a spreadsheet into an array using getDisplayValues() and compare different elements to each other. But when comparing two elements they always evaluate as unequal, even when they aren't. This seems to be because all the elements are objects, though getDisplayValues() should return strings.

```
var ids = sheet.getRange(row,col,sheetHeight).getDisplayValues();

//comparing identical elements
Logger.log(ids[4] == ids[5]);
Logger.log(typeof(ids[4]));
Logger.log(typeof(ids[5]));
```

Logs

```
false
object
object
```

How can I get this to evaluate correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[getRange method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow-column-numrows) return a Range, which is a bi-dimensionnal array, even if you have a single column. You must compare what could be like :

```
var ids = sheet.getRange(row,col,sheetHeight).getDisplayValues();

//comparing identical elements
Logger.log(ids[4][0] == ids[5][0]);
Logger.log(typeof(ids[4][0]));
Logger.log(typeof(ids[5][0]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, just a small variation in your code.

```
var ids = sheet.getRange(row,col,sheetHeight).getDisplayValues().filter(String).toString();

//comparing identical elements
Logger.log(ids[4] == ids[5]);
Logger.log(typeof(ids[4]));
Logger.log(typeof(ids[5]));
```

Comment: I think that you've got a little problem on your solution: ids will be a string, so you can't use array index on it.